# Happy number error

Tags: math

So. I wrote a snippet to execute a program just to confirm whether a number is a happy number or not. But it doesn't work for any number except powers of 10. Could you please point out the problem..
And yeah it compiles alright.

```
    while(true)
    {
        while (num>0)
        {
            dig=num%10;
            sum=sum+(dig*dig);
            num=num/10;
        }
        num=sum;
        if(num==1)
        System.out.println("Happy");
        break;
    }
```

}
}

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm appears to be flawed.  For one thing, you don't detect unhappy numbers.

From [Wikipedia's page on happy numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number):

> A happy number is defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), **or it loops endlessly** in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy numbers (or sad numbers).

(Emphasis mine.)

Translation:  You'd have to repeat the process til you end up with a value you recognize as part of a cycle.  Iff that value is 1, the number is happy.  If it's not, and you don't detect that, you'll end up looping forever.

Answer (score 1):

Foremost, you are not resetting sum to zero.

Also, any non-happy number will loop indefinitely.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the fact that `sum` was never initialized in the loop.  +1

Comment: If I recall, you can determine a non-happy number in a finite set because all in the set end up with the same sequence of digits.

Answer (score 0):

using this function will find you happy,sad numbers

```
#include <cmath>
long fun(long);

long func(long x)
{
long sum=0,rem;
while(x>0)
{
    num=x%10;
    sum=sum+pow(rem,2);
    x=x/10;
}
if(sum>=10)
    func(sum);
else
return sum;
}
```